# How to define a many to one mapping in hibernate (XML based) based on non-primary key columns

Tags: java, hibernate

**Scenario:**

Two tables User and UserGroup

Sample **User** Table desc below

```
Name          Null     Type          
------------- -------- ------------- 
ID                     VARCHAR2(12)  
USERGROUP              VARCHAR2(32)   
ROLE_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
```

Sample **UserGroup** Table desc below

```
Name                Null     Type          
------------------- -------- ------------- 
ID                           VARCHAR2(12)  
NAME                         VARCHAR2(32)     
ROLE_ID             NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
```

From above tables, `UserGroup + ROLE_ID` in User table is linked to `NAME + ROLE_ID` in UserGroup

I need to write one to many mapping for above relation, so i can get UserGroup object from User object. I have defined below relation in user.hbm but it is not working.

```
<join table="USR_GROUP" fetch="join" optional="true">
        <key property-ref="nonprimary">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </key>
        <many-to-one name="UserGroup" column="USERGROUP" formula="ROLE_ID"
            class="someclass" entity-name="someclass"
            not-null="true">

        </many-to-one>
    </join
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: While I see, that you have taken some effort on writing the question (which does not seem to be as usual as one might guess) I am missing what exactly you tried to overcome the issue? What did you do? Where are you stuck? Please see [mcve].

Comment: i need to join two tables on non-primary key from User (UserGroup + ROLE_ID are non-primary key) and UserGroup (NAME + ROLE_ID are non-primary key).

Comment: Im going with this is wrong `class="someclass" entity-name="someclass"`

Comment: it is sample model name i have mentioned ..you can assume it as UserGroup model and entity class